# Arangodb delimitter Analyzer

Tags: arangodb

I want to create an analyzer to tokenize characters instead of words. 
for example, Foo will be tokenized to [ 'F', 'o', 'o']  so that the TFIDF search will be based on the frequency of characters instead of words...

I tried out the below but doesn't seem to work.

a.save('emailAnalyzer1', 'delimiter', {local : 'en.UTF-8', case: 'upper', delimiter: '' , stopwords: ['@','+','.']})

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm totally not sure if this is still relevant and if this is the solution, but you wrote `local` instead of `locale`.

Comment: Also, a delimiter analyzer only allows the property `delimiter`. So the `case` field and others will be ignored.